# ld: library not found for -lCocoaLumberjack

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode8, linker-errors

I updated pods for `SalesforceSDKCore 4.3.1` and `SalesforceRESTApi 4.3.1`. When I did `pod install` it in turn installed cocoaLumberjack library which is a dependent library I suppose. After successful install of Pods, I couldn't build successfully, as I am getting this error -

> ld: library not found for -lCocoaLumberjack
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I deleted my Library search paths, added/deleted inerited in Other linker Flags, nothing seem to work. These are my search path and other linker flag settings.

[image: Library Search Path]

[image: Other Linker Flags]

My Pod file -

```
# platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Custom' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic  frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for Custom
  source 'https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Specs.git'
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'SalesforceSDKCore'
pod 'XMLDictionary', '~> 1.4'
pod 'SalesforceNetwork'
pod 'SmartStore'
pod 'SmartSync'

end
```

Comment: Have you try to remove reference of your Library .a file and again add it at same path ?

Comment: How to remove libCocoaLumberjack.a file? It is in Pods-> Products folder.

I tried adding .a file in Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries sepearately. Still I had the issue..

Comment: so you are using CocoaPod so you are trying with workspace or in project ? can you post your pod file here ?

Comment: Update: Copied Pod file content.

Comment: Be careful. `'SalesforceSDKCore', '~> 4.3.1'` needs `CocoaLumberjack '~> 2.3.0'`, but according to your PodFile, you don't specify the version, which should be the last one 3.1 and you may encounter issues about duplicate. I'd suggest to remove `CocoaLumberjack` from your PodFile, and use the version from `SalesforceSDKCore`.

Comment: @Larme I initially did that. I was getting same error, so tried adding it separately.

Comment: Now, updated my pod with latest available, still getting this error.

Comment: If I navigate to Cocoalumberjack folder in Pods, I could see only CocoaLumberjack.modulemap in Framework folder. libCocoaLumberjack.a file is missing.  Can this be a reason? How will I fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to run in the project or the workspace? If you add pods, it creates a workspace, and you should no longer use the xcproject to build, but rather than xcworkspace.

Comment: I am running workspace and not the xcodeproj.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried many solutions, some of them are:

1. File/Workspace Settings/Derived Data Arrow -> Delete DerivedData folder, empty trash
2. Terminal -> pod deintegrate , pod install

If you renamed your target's name, then:

3. Target/Build Settings/Test Host :: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/TargetName.app/TargetName

I really hate this *linker command failed* problem. I get it all the time and every time I need to follow another solution to solve this. I must have given over 30 hours of my life to this s#$t.